# tag pages... session variables or many static pages?

Tags: html, session, static, tags

i have a website which contains many news articles. IN the database, each article has so-called "tags" which the user sees displayed alongside the article. When the user clicks on the tag, they are directed to a list of other articles also containing this tag.

Should I generate a distinct HTML page for each newly created tag, or should I create one single page and vary the content based on what tag the user clicked on using session variables????

obviously, the pages will not be completely static since I will update them everytime a new article with a matching tag is uploaded

Comment: I can concieve both methods might work... I want to know which one is easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly shouldn't use session data. That is for data that needs to persist, but it set on a per user basis. Using it for per-request data will just break bookmarking and introduce race conditions.

You should have a distinct URI for each tag. It doesn't matter (from an end user perspective) if you use dynamically generated content (either via a query string, or parsing the URI in your server side code (most frameworks, e.g. [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/), will handle this for you)) or if you use generated static pages.

Static pages make it easier to handle caching and give better performance on very high traffic systems, but tend to require a rebuild of large sections of the site if content changes. You can get similar performance improvements by using server side caching (e.g. via [memcached](http://memcached.org/)).

Dynamic pages are usually simpler to implement.

Comment: this means i will have to auto-generate a new html-page every time a new tag is introduced... i'm not sure how to do that... any tips?

Comment: You have a table of tags in your database, and a many-to-many bridging table that maps tags to articles. Then just loop over the tags and generate a page for each using the list of articles you get by joining via the bridge (sorted in whatever order you want). If you are working with static files, output it to a file each other. If you are working dynamically, then just generate when a tag index page is requested (and 404 if the tag isn't in the DB).

Comment: Alternatively … use an existing CMS that implements tags instead of building your own from scratch.

Comment: it's kinda of too late for that... kinda wished i had used wordpress or something.. but i already basically built everything from scratch so I'm not gonna switch now...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a listing page that contains title and small description of all articles containing a particular tag similar to WordPress.

For example, here is listing page for the tag `jQuery`:

- http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/tag/jquery/

Comment: this is good idea... i'm just concerned about the creation of these tag pages because I will have a very large number of tags...

Comment: @Timtam: Yes you should create one listing page in similar fasion, it will be a lot more easier and without much overhead :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create one page, and then rewrite the url so that it referenced the tag page so something like this

```
Tag element == New

tagpage.aspx 

http://www.yourwebsite.com/New.aspx
```

this allows you to have one page to update the content with but allows each page to be indexed by Google.com.

I'm not sure what language you are using but I would look up URL rewriting

here's a link for rewriting in apache:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

here's a link for rewriting in asp.net:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Comment: @Timtam yes but I don't have any experience with it so you would have to do some research on it here's a quick link to a page on using .htaccess to rewrite your url based on regex etc. http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php